# Why is my vega-lite tooltip attached to a rule so slow

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have [this vega-lite chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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) (based on the seattle-weather data).

It includes a vertical "rule" mark that moves on hover, and has a tooltip attached to it. I find that the rule feels very sluggish in following the mouse, and I think it's because it's trying to determine when the mouse stops moving.

Does anyone have ideas on why this actually happens and anything I can do to mitigate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of datapoints on that x-axis. VL is highlighting each in turn and it takes time for it to catch up. Have a play with the throttle and debounce settings and consider disabling nearest. e.g.

[Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/event-streams/

```
 "params": [
        {
          "name": "hover",
          "select": {
            "fields": ["date"],
            "on": {"type": "mouseover", "debounce": 0},
            "type": "point"
          }
        }
      ],
```

Comment: Thanks. Removing `nearest` and adding `debounce` didn't help, but removing `clear` made a big difference.